# Leaflet JS auto pan longitude

Tags: javascript, latitude-longitude, leaflet

I'm trying to build a map that pans by a few relative degrees a second by longitude, but I'm only seeing a way to pan by a number of pixels.  This means it pans farther when zoomed out than zoomed in.  What's a clean way to do this?

Here's the code I'm using to pan right now:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    minZoom: 1,
    maxZoom: 6,
    worldCopyJump: true,
}).setView([0, 0], 3);

L.tileLayer('maps/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { 
    maxNativeZoom: 3,
    reuseTiles: true,
    unloadInvisibleTiles: false
}).addTo(map);

setInterval(function(){map.panBy([100, 0], {animate: true, duration: 1});}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always convert latlng to pixels http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-project

Or you just use panTo http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-panto Which takes latlng

Comment: That should work, do I need to pass it an absolute latlng coordinate offset by a few degrees from center or will it return a relative distance by default?

Comment: panTo uses an absolute latlng, so you will need to add some amount to the current value of the center, which is easy to get http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-getcenter